# Calling WCF service inside the Host process

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have an architecture question about calling consuming WCF service.

Currently, my WCF services contains 2 functions SubmitJob and ProcessQueueJobs

1. The SubmitJob puts a job into a single queue and this can by call by many clients
2. The ProcessQueueJobs will process all jobs in the queue and I don’t want to have a service contract on this method and I don’t want the SubmitJob calls the ProcessQueueJobs

So, the simplest way for me to call the ProcessQueueJobs is to have a service contract and warp around by a simple console app and schedule to run it every few minutes. I don’t like this solution much since I don’t want to expose the ProcessQueueJob to client.
So what is the best way to run the ProcessQueueJobs inside the process that host the WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

I have a controller class that is used by the WCF interfaces (I have SOAP and REST interfaces).

So, when someone calls to `SubmitJob` then I would pass that to the controller.

In the controller function it will save it to the queue.

Now, in my project I have a queue that is defined in this class:

```
public static class WebServiceControllerStatic
{
   static ConcurrentQueue<WebServiceModels.Job> jobqueue = new ConcurrentQueue<WebServiceModels.Job>();
```

Then I have these two methods, one to put the info into the queue and then the other to start the thread to process the queue.

```
    public static WebServiceModels.Job[] JobQueue
    {
        set
        {
            value.AsParallel().ForAll(i => jobqueue.Enqueue(i));
        }
    }
    public static void ProcessUpdateJobQueue()
    {
        Action UpdateJob = () =>
        {
            if (jobqueue.IsEmpty)
                return;
            int cnt = 0;
            Parallel.For(0, jobqueue.Count, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 },
                (j) =>
                {
                    cnt++;
                });
        };
        if (processUpdateJobThread == null)
        {
            processUpdateJobThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    UpdateJob();
                    UpdateJob();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            });
            processUpdateJobThread.Start();
        }
    }
```

And in my controller method I call this, whenever, in your case, a SubmitJob call is made:

```
WebServiceControllerStatic.JobQueue = jobs;
WebServiceControllerStatic.ProcessUpdateJobQueue();
```

So, I have one queue that will hold what needs to be processed, and a thread that starts up every so often to process whatever is in the queue.

And this works well for my needs.

I used a ConcurrentQueue mainly because I will update and remove from the queue at the same time.

Comment: OK I see. You created a separate thread to run the ProcessUpdateJobQueue with infinite loop and sleep 1 sec after each loop.

Comment: @AustinTX - Yes, that was the best solution I could find for my needs, but it is every 10 seconds that it starts in my case.